# How to make plotly faster in shiny

Tags: performance, caching, input, shiny, plotly

I wonder if there is any good way to speed up the plotly performance especially for their speed. Currently I am trying to isolate the data for plots and only leave two inputs to reactively change the plotly content.

What I was confused is that when I tested those poltly plots with fixed data (I did isolate in shiny) the plots running pretty fast when changing those two inputs. However, when I import the same logic in shiny using isolate() and two inputs the polts running extremely slow.

Please help.

Here is my current codes, Thanks

```
observe({
##### Visualization - Daily Pattern #####
output$TTPlotB<-renderPlotly({

  #input$file_load

  #data_daily<-

  #data_daily2<<-data_daily
  date1<-input$dateRange[1]
  date2<-input$dateRange[2]
  journey1<-input$journey[1]
  journey2<-input$journey[2]

  plot_ly(isolate({Alloc()})%>%
            filter(date_range>= date1 & date_range<=date2 )%>% 
            filter(Days_in_journey %in%  ( journey1:journey2 ))%>%
            group_by(date_range,OEM,daily_available)%>%
            summarise(ngm=min(daily_avail_ngm),  ### use the min based on the selected journey 
                      product=min(daily_avail_product), ### use the min based on the selected journey 
                      lp=min(daily_avail_lp), ### use the min based on the selected journey 
                      cart=min(daily_avail_cart), ### use the min based on the selected journey 
                      email=min(daily_avail_email))%>%
            gather(channel,channel_daily_avail,-c(date_range,OEM,daily_available))%>%
            select(-c(daily_available))%>%
            spread(OEM,channel_daily_avail)%>%
            group_by(date_range,channel)%>%
            mutate(Daily_tot=sum(HP,Dell,Lenovo,Acer,Asus,Others))%>%
            mutate(D_HP_avai=round(100*HP/(input$OEM.HP.Aud.wk*1000/7),0))%>%
            mutate(D_Dell_avai=round(100*Dell/(input$OEM.Dell.Aud.wk*1000/7),0))%>%
            mutate(D_Leno_avai=round(100*Lenovo/(input$OEM.Lenovo.Aud.wk*1000/7),0))%>%
            mutate(D_Acer_avai=round(100*Acer/(input$OEM.Acer.Aud.wk*1000/7),0))%>%
            mutate(D_Asus_avai=round(100*Asus/(input$OEM.Asus.Aud.wk*1000/7),0))%>%
            mutate(D_Oth_avai=round(100*Others/(input$OEM.Others.Aud.wk*1000/7),0))%>%as.data.table()
          ,
          height = 500, width = 1450,
          x=~date_range,
          y=~Daily_tot,
          type="scatter",
          color=~channel, 
          mode="lines+markers",
          hoverinfo = 'text',
          text = ~paste('</br> <B> Channel:</B>', channel
                        ,
                        '</br> <B> Total Available Machines:</B>', formatC(Daily_tot, format="d", big.mark=","),
                        '</br> <B> Selected Date:</B>',date_range,
                        '</br> <B> HP: </B>',formatC(HP, format="d", big.mark=","),',',round(100*HP/Daily_tot,0),'%',
                        ' <B> HP Daily:</B>',D_HP_avai,'%' ,

                        '</br> <B> Dell: </B>',formatC(Dell, format="d", big.mark=","),',',round(100*Dell/Daily_tot,0),'%',
                        ' <B> Dell Daily:</B>',D_Dell_avai ,'%',

                        '</br> <B> Lenovo: </B>',formatC(Lenovo, format="d", big.mark=","),',',round(100*Lenovo/Daily_tot,0),'%',
                        ' <B> Lenovo Daily:</B>',D_Leno_avai ,'%',

                        '</br> <B> Acer: </B>',formatC(Acer, format="d", big.mark=","),',',round(100*Acer/Daily_tot,0),'%',
                        ' <B> Acer Daily:</B>', D_Acer_avai,'%',

                        '</br> <B> Asus: </B>',formatC(Asus, format="d", big.mark=","),',',round(100*Asus/Daily_tot,0),'%',
                        ' <B> Asus Daily:</B>',D_Asus_avai ,'%',

                        '</br> <B> Others: </B>',formatC(Others, format="d", big.mark=","),',',round(100*Others/Daily_tot,0),'%',
                        ' <B> Other Daily:</B>',D_Oth_avai ,'%'
          )

  )%>%
    layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Dates'),
           yaxis = list(title = 'Available Machines')
    )
})
```

})